# The eigenvalues of $vv^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The problem is vector $v$ is a nonzero vector in $R^n$ with $n \ge 2$. Then find all eigenvalues of $n×n$ matrix $vv^T$.

I have already known that $0$ is one of its eigenvalues. Is there any other eigenvalues? If yes, how to find them? If no, how to prove that $0$ is the only eigenvalue?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: what is $(vv^\top)v\,?$ What is $(vv^\top)^2\,?$

Comment: Hint: rotate $v$ to $|v|(1,0,0,\dots,0)$ and solve that easy problem.

Comment: Geometric interpretation : If the norm of $v$ is one, $vv^T$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the line $\mathbb{R}$, therefore with spectrum $(1,0,0,...0)$

Comment: well one other obvious eigen value is $|v|^{2}$ as $vv^{T}v=|v|^{2}v$. I dont know if this awnsers your question.

Comment: @AidanR.S. Why $vv^Tv=|v|^2v$?

Comment: @RuizhePang Well matrix multiplication is associative and $v^{T}v$ is just the dot product of $v$ with itself which gives the square magnitude of the vector. You then just have a left over $v$ that then gives one of the eigen values to be the square magnatude of the vector.

Comment: @AidanR.S. Oh, I see.  Thanks a lot.